# como coger un array en una vistar navbar de blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

### Alguien sabe como coger un array que pido en un controller en un navbar que tengo como blade?

Quiero pedir esta query en mi navbar:

os dejo mi codigo, esto es el controlador

```
class CategoriaController extends Controller

{ 
   /**
   * Display a listing of the resource. 
   * 
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
   */
   public function index() {

        $categorias=Categoria::all();

        return view('layouts.sidebar', compact('categorias'));
   }
```

luego tengo la ruta:

```
Route::get('layouts.sidebar', [CategoriaController::class, 'index'])->name('arrayCategorias');
```

y por ultimo la vista donde quiero ir imprimiendo el array dinamicamente con un foreach

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="#hombre" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidebarProfile"> Hombre
  </a>
  <div class="collapse menu-dropdown" id="sidebarProfile">
    <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p>{{dd($categorias)}}</p>

        <!-- aqui iria un bucle con el array pero estoy probando a imprimirlo primero -->
        <a href="pages-profile.html" class="nav-link">
          ETC... </a>
      </li>
      <!-- Fin del bucle -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

adjunto imagen que se me olvido antes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops

Comment: si, el problema no es tema de loop, es que quiero trabajar con el array de la query, pero me dice que esta undefinded, creo que es por que estoy devolviendo mal las vistas o algo

Comment: Si te fijas quien t da el problema es tu Index, no tu vista de sidebar, el index esta tratando de buscar esa variable pero no existe, imagino que desde tu index haces un include del sidebar, en ese caso quien deberia recibir la variable categoria seria tu index

Comment: hola heyner muchas gracias por responder, el problema esque quiero usarlo en todas las paginas no solo en el index, si lo paso al index solo me deja usarlo en el index verdad?

Comment: Eso íltimo que comentas está explicado en la documentación [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ eres dios amigo

Comment: Vale. Si te animas, agrega una respuesta explicando cómo lo resolviste. Puedes guiarte por [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)